# How do you continuously input from Java program to EXE's console?

Tags: java, user-input, java-stream

I have an ***EXE*** file, `addOne.exe` which continuously gets an integer input from the user on the console **(NOT command line parameters)** and outputs the *integer +  1* onto the console . Sample output is shown below:

```
1
2

6
7

29
30
...
```

I have already made the EXE outputs work, that is, Whenever the EXE outputs text to the console, print that text from the **Java program**.
I am trying to:

- Get **user input** from the **Java program** using `Scanner.nextInt()` and input to the EXE as console input
- I need to send the input one at a time, which means that simply closing the BufferedWriter stream at the end of the program and inputting the stream into the EXE all at once won't work.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\addOne.exe");
...
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
while (!input.equals("exit")) {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin))) {
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        writer.write(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CmdLineTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
}
```

However, whenever I run this code, the first iteration of the while loop (the first time I input something) is able to send the input to the EXE, but after the first iteration, the error `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed` is given.

How can I continue to get user input from a `Scanner.nextInt()` inside a while loop

Thank you.

---

**Edit:** `writer.flush()` does not seem to input the user input from the Java program to the EXE.

---

**Edit:** see my answer below

Comment: Move the writer construction to before the loop.

Comment: @khelwood I still get the same error after the first iteration of the while loop though, because I close the OutputStream on every iteration.
If I don't close the OutputStream on every iteration of the while loop though, then the java program never outputs the input from the java program to the EXE.

Comment: Don't close your stream every iteration. You can flush it without closing. Why is your *Out*putStream variable called `stdin` ?

Comment: @khelwood I tried flushing the stream, but flushing doesnt seem to output the stream to the EXE. Only closing the stream outputs the stream to the EXE.
The _Out_putStream variable is called `stdin` because the input from the user of the java program gets inputted into the EXE.

Comment: You should post the complete code using the `flush()` call, obviously, you are doing something wrong. Besides that, there’s no sense in using a `BufferedWriter` when all you want is *no buffering*. Not that you could get rid of all the nonsensical buffering around there, as `process.getOutputStream()` already returns a `BufferedOutputStream`…

Comment: @Holger it seems that the `flush()` call still inputted the stream into the EXE, but a `newLine()` call was required to **enter** the input into the EXE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using writer.flush() inputted the stream into the EXE, but the stream required a writer.newLine() before the input was processed by the EXE, as the console requires the enter key to be pressed after the input.

Here is the working code:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        writer.write(input);
        System.out.println("IN: "+input);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CmdLineTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the scope of your `try` and `while` statements so that you're only making 1 `BufferedWriter`. When your try-with-resources code block ends, the writer is closed and by extension `stdin` is as well. Thus no more writers can be made for that object.

```
try([resources]) {
    while([condition]) {
        ...
    }
} catch(IOException ex) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I don't close my writer though, then the OutputStream never outputs the input from the java program to the EXE...

Comment: add `writer.flush()` just before the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: writer.flush() does not seem to output the OutputStream and the BufferedWriter to the EXE. Also, I need the output to be sent to the EXE for every iteration of the while loop, not at the end of the while loop.

Comment: That's why I said before the end, meaning the last line of the loop itself.

Comment: I put the writer.flush() before the end of the while loop where you told me to  now, so that the stream is flushed for every iteration. However, the `writer.flush()` still does not output the input from the `Scanner.nextLine()` until I **close** the program.